# Search within database field

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a job search site where candidates can register themselves for various jobs . Also employers can post jobs with multiple qualification (eg if he wants MBA or Phd it will be saved in database like mba,phd . I want to show jobs for the registered candidates which are relevant to his educational qualification . So I am confused how can I do this because I think I have to search within database . Please help.

```
if($cid >0 )           //If the candidate is registered
    {
        $quali = $this->getCandidatesQualification($cid);

        $cond = "WHERE ";               //I want to put a condition if he is registered with us , it will show jobs a/c to his qualification 
    }
```

UPDATE :

```
$cond = "";
    if($cid >0 )
    {
        $quali = $this->getCandidatesQualification($cid);

        $cond = "WHERE emp_qualification LIKE '%$quali%'";
    }


    $sql = "SELECT
            emp_job_id,emp_job_profie,emp_qualification,emp_experience
        FROM
            tbl_emp_data
            $cond
        ORDER BY job_add_date DESC LIMIT 0,10   
    ";
```

// Query Search all jobs

```
$sql = "SELECT
                emp_job_id,emp_job_profie,emp_qualification,emp_experience
            FROM
                tbl_emp_data
            ORDER BY job_add_date DESC LIMIT 0,10   
        ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the LIKE keyword - for example,

```
        SELECT
            emp_job_id,emp_job_profie,emp_qualification,emp_experience
        FROM
            tbl_emp_data
        WHERE emp_qualification LIKE '%MBA%'
        ORDER BY job_add_date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Here, the '%' wildcard is used for any number of characters before or after MBA, so it will find it in strings like `MBA`, `BTech, MBA`, `BCom, MBA, PhD`.

Comment: Thanks . I was also thinking about it . Now I am confirmed . Please check my updated query and let me know if I am writing the correct query.

Comment: Yes it should work. In future, it is always better to try it out and see if it works, rather than ask someone always

Comment: Be aware that a wildcard prefixed LIKE clause cannot use an index and does not scale well.  For what you are doing, it would likely be better to use something like lucene, sphinx, solar, etc for searching this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

set a colum in your `tbl_emp_data` names `'is_registered'` type `ENUM`  and set two value **('0','1')**

and then set WHERE condition

```
WHERE is_registered = 1
```